# How to Get Top Value from a Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Is there a way to get top row from a stored procedure ?

SQL Server stored procedure

```
EXEC SelectedJobTypeList
┌─────────────┬──────────────┐
│ JobTypeCode | JobTypeName  |
├─────────────┼──────────────┤
│             | Select All   |
├─────────────┼──────────────┤
│ A1          | Road work    |
├─────────────┼──────────────┤
│ B1          | Design       |
├─────────────┼──────────────┤
│ C1          | Build        |
└─────────────┴──────────────┘
```

Expected Result

```
┌─────────────┬──────────────┐
│ JobTypeCode | JobTypeName  |
├─────────────┼──────────────┤
│             | Select All   |
└─────────────┴──────────────┘
```

Comment: Change your select in the SP to select top 1?

Comment: instea d of a select create a tempory table and select top1 from it, but i don't uinderstand why this is top 1 if there is no sign of order to it

Comment: If the results from the procedure are ordered you could insert...exec using a temp table with identity.

Comment: Maybe transform your procedure into an inline Table Function, then you can do `select top 1 * from dbo.yourfunction()`

Comment: I work from a client side and pulling data from servers which I limited access to but I can use the created stored stored procedures.

Comment: @Moyura please don't add your answer to your question - add another answer if its helpful, although your answer doesn't really answer the question you asked, you've solved your actual problem, but not the posted problem.

Comment: @tinazmu no need to delete you answer - its valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example may be oversimplified because it doesn't appear necessary to call a SP just to be returned "Select All". However assuming you do need to call the SP in your case, you would have far more control if you capture the results into a temp table and then select the row you are interested in. And while you could use `TOP 1` you will have a more robust solution if you have a way to select a specific row.

Here is an example

```
-- Ensure these datatypes exactly match the data being returned by your SP
CREATE TABLE #tempJobTypeList (JobTypeCode VARCHAR(2), JobTypeName VARCHAR(32));

INSERT INTO #tempJobTypeList (JobTypeCode, JobTypeName)
EXEC SelectedJobTypeList;

SELECT JobTypeCode, JobTypeName
FROM #tempJobTypeList
WHERE JobTypeName = '';

DROP TABLE #tempJobTypeList;
```

Comment: Thanks @Dale K, I also tried to use CTE table, but I ended up using
`SELECT '' as JobTypeCode, 'Select All' as JobTypeName`

Comment: @Moyura are you saying this solution didn't work? Or just that you went with the simpler solution in the end?

Comment: Correct, I went with the simple solution.